# Changing Image Using Button iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton

I have a `UIImageView *picture`

and a `UIButton *next`

and an

```
- (IBAction)next {
}
```

I want to change the image on the view but only if the image equals... for example img1

But using the same button I want to also be able to change the picture if the image = img2 but to a different image (img3)

So far I have this code but it gives me errors:

```
- (IBAction)next {
    if (picture UIImage = imageNamed:@"img01.jpg") {
    [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img02.jpg"
    }
    if (picture UIImage = imageNamed:@"img02.jpg") {
    [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img03.jpg"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out now all I did was forget to put .jpg on the end of the img%i ;)

```
- (IBAction)next {
     static int index = 0;  // <-- here
    index++;
    // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
    int imageCount=16;
    if (index<=imageCount) {
        NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i", index];
        [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use static variables unless you have a pressing need. You now have no way outside this function to get the image index.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)next {
    picture.tag++;
    [picture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%02d.jpg",1+(picture.tag%2)]
    ]];
}
```

should be the simplest solution.

**edit** on first click, goes to `img02.jpg`, on second click back to `img01.jpg` again. Increase the `2` to allow for `img03.jpg` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)next {
    if ([[picture image] isEqual: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img01.jpg"]]) {

       [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img02.jpg"]];

    } else if ([[picture image] isEqual: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img02.jpg"]]) {

       [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img03.jpg"]];
    }
}
```

Also, this is a pretty rudimentary way of changing the image.  A more elegant way would be to have a global `int` that had the current image index, so clicking "next" would simply increase that count.  Then, if an image exists with that name, switch to it:

// Declare index in Header.h

```
index=0;

- (IBAction)next {
    index++;
    // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
    int imageCount=2;
    if (index<=imageCount) {
        NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%02i", index];
        [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    }
}
```

Comment: IT just quits the application??

Comment: Please could you help it says UIImageView may not respond to UIImage

Comment: EDITED- sorry i forgot ending ")" in the if statement.  Also, my second example might be more useful for using more than 3 images.

Comment: Sorry how do I declare something?

Comment: Please help do I use #define?

Comment: In your header file, look after... "@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {"... and add: "int index;"

Comment: Don't use global vars unless there's no alternative, and change the `%i` to `%02i` at least since this will give the OP another headache.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIImageView` and add a `enum` property in the header:

```
typedef enum _PictureType {
    PictureTypeFirstImage = 0,
    PictureTypeSecondImage,
    PictureTypeThirdImage,
    PictureTypes
} PictureType;

@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {
    PictureType type;
}

@property (readwrite) PictureType type;
```

In the implementation:

```
@synthesize type;
```

When initializing your `picture`:

```
[picture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img01.jpg"]];
picture.type = PictureTypeFirstImage;
```

In your action method:

```
- (IBAction) next {
    switch (picture.type) {
        case (PictureTypeFirstImage): {
            [picture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img02.jpg"]];
            picture.type = PictureTypeSecondImage;
            break;
        }
        case (PictureTypeSecondImage): {
            [picture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img03.jpg"]];
            picture.type = PictureTypeThirdImage;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: error: no type or storage class may be specified here before 'implementation'


/Users/Will/Desktop/SUC/Classes/Pictures.m:15:0 /Users/Will/Desktop/SUC/Classes/Pictures.m:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'synthesize'


/Users/Will/Desktop/SUC/Classes/Pictures.m:41:0 /Users/Will/Desktop/SUC/Classes/Pictures.m:41: fatal error: method declaration not in @interface context

Comment: I get those errors please help
 error: no type or storage class may be specified here before 'implementation' 

error: expected identifier or '(' before 'synthesize

Comment: When you subclass `UIImageView`, the subclass needs its own separate header and implementation files.

Comment: Why subclass if you have a `.tag` property for exactly that purpose?

Comment: Can't understand why you would make things so complicated if the OP doesn't even get basic C syntax right. (no offense btw)

Comment: Yeesh, you're right. `UIImageView` has a `tag` property. Of course. I feel stupid. Feel free to ignore my answer.